# Remove GPS Location

Tags: gps

I have a few pictures taken with the GPS on.
Now, I would like to share the photos with some of my friends, and let them guess where it is.
How can I remove the GPS location from the pictures?
I'm using a Windows 8.1 computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In recent versions of Windows (Vista or newer), you can do this as standard.

1. Right click on your photo, and click "Properties".
2. On the properties window, select the "Details" tab. At the bottom of that tab, click the option for "Remove Properties and Personal Information".
3. Then that lets you create a copy with all possible properties removed, or select specific properties to remove from the file. So you can just remove the tags for GPS latitude and longitude.

[image: Remove properties screenshot]
(screenshot from Windows 7, other versions may be slightly different)

Answer (score 4):

Windows Explorer, conversely to much advice, cannot fully clean GPS metadata, and sometimes cannot recognize it (e.g., pictures taken with a Windows Phone).

I suggest you use exiftool, it's probably the best way to do tag management for pictures. It's a command-line tool, although there are also GUIs for it.

To remove (EXIF) GPS tags, you should use this command:

**exiftool.exe -gps:all=** *FILENAME*

e.g.,

`exiftool.exe -gps:all= WP_20150928_22_47_06_Pro.jpg`

to remove GPS tags from all the .jpg files in the current folder:

`exiftool.exe -gps:all= *.jpg`

You can find exif tool here:
https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Here is a more specific thread on this topic:
http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=6037.0

Answer (score 1):

On my iPad, where I now do most of my pre- and sometimes my post-production on images, I use an app called EXIF Editor.

This app will allow you to remove or change up to 29 GPS fields, including if your camera records the name of the satellite used, distances from where you live, altitude,  etc., and change just about every field except for the manufacturer's fields, such as camera name/model, serial number, owner's name (If you updated that) and firmware installed.

If I recall, I think you can select a group of images and do a batch edit.

The app is available in the App Store.

George.

Answer (score 1):

In [Digikam](https://www.digikam.org/) you can simply click on Tools/Edit Geolocation [image: Tools/Edit Geolocation]

and then remove the GPS data for all selected images by removing the check mark.
[image: remove the GPS data]

Answer (score -2):

Use any file tag editor.Example: http://www.photome.de

Comment: What would you do with such a tag editor? Why that example?